# How to pull a sentence from a log file on multiple remote computers

Tags: powershell

I am needing to pull a specific sentence from a log file on multiple remote computers. I have all of the computer names already but I do not know how to go about pulling contents of a file from them and copying all of it to a file so that I can reference the sentence from each computer with its machine name. Basically each machine has a specific number unique to itself that we need.

Before explaining, I assume powershell is the tool to use for this.

There are about 1800 machines and I have a variable for all of those. Then I assume I have to make a loop of some kind that runs on each of those machines.

the loop would pull the text from that file that I need and save it all to a file. I am basically pretty new in my Net Admin position with not a lot of PowerShell experience and I wondered if anyone could help.

```bsh
$computers = ***list of computers***

$computers | ForEachObject{ 
    Add-Content -Path C:\Users\Public\Activant\Eagle\3log.log -Value "Terminal information for ***need the info that is here***"
}
```

Get-Content -Path .\TERMINAL NUMBERS.txt

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do what you want. [*grin*] it builds a scriptblock that does the work, hands that off to `Invoke-Command` with a list of systems to run it on, gathers the results, creates a list of `$Non-Responders`, removes unwanted properties added by the `I-C` cmdlet, and finally shows the two collections.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ComputerNameList = @'
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$IC_ScriptBlock = {
    $TargetFileName = 'C:\Temp\Grouping-Strings-List_2019-07-31.log'
    # the " \b\w+\b \b\w+\b " is two words delimited by spaces
    #    so this will find any line that has two words between the listed phrases
    $LinePattern = '^Acid Drum \b\w+\b \b\w+\b Psychedelic$'
    # the next line is a no-match patern for testing
    #$LinePattern = '^Acid Drum \b\w+\b$'

    $Line =  (Get-Content -LiteralPath $TargetFileName |
        Select-String -Pattern $LinePattern).Line

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Line))
        {
        $Line = '__Not Found__'
        }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        LineText = $Line
        }
    }
$IC_Params = @{
    ComputerName = $ComputerNameList
    ScriptBlock = $IC_ScriptBlock
    # comment out the next line to see any errors in the I-C call
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }

$Responders = Invoke-Command @IC_Params

$Non_Responders = $ComputerNameList.Where({$_ -notin $Responders.PSComputerName})
# the next line removes unwated properties added by "Invoke-Command"
$Responders = $Responders |
    Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId

$Responders
'=' * 40
$Non_Responders
```

output ...

```
ComputerName LineText                               
------------ --------                               
[MySysName]  Acid Drum Instrumental Live Psychedelic
[MySysName]  Acid Drum Instrumental Live Psychedelic
========================================
10.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
```

if needed, you can create a single collection from the two above fairly directly. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are trying to do is to **READ** the line from a file all computers in your list should have, located at `C:\Users\Public\Activant\Eagle\3log.log`

In that case, something like below should work:

```
# use UNC naming for the remote file path
$inputFile  = 'C$\Users\Public\Activant\Eagle\3log.log'  # I'm guessing this is the file you want to read
$outputFile = 'C:\TERMINAL NUMBERS.txt'
$computers  = ***list of computers***                    # the array of computer names

$result = $computers | ForEach-Object { 
    # test if the computer is online
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # create the full UNC path by prepending the common file path with the computer name
        $file = '\\{0}\{1}' -f $_, $inputFile

        # test if the file can be found or not
        if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $file -PathType Leaf) {
            # using non regex string search
            $line = (Select-String -LiteralPath $file -Pattern "whatever you're looking for" -SimpleMatch).Line
            if (!$line) {
                # the file is there, but the pattern was not found
                $line = "Pattern not found"
            }
        }
        else {
            $line = "File '$inputFile' not found."
        }
    }
    else {
        $line = 'Computer is Off-Line'
    }

    # Finally, add this info to your text file
    Add-Content -Path $outputFile -Value "$_ --> $line"
    # And emit an object for the $result collection. This will display nicely on screen,
    # but also allow for the creation of a CSV file which might be better as output.
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Computer' = $_
        'LogInfo'  = $line
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can read the output text file or (better I think) use the $result collection for output:

On screen:

```
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

To CSV file

```
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\TERMINAL NUMBERS.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```